# No EJB module found

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ejb

I'm new to development and I want to use EJB in javaEE, 
My code is simple, I want to create an instance and insert it into DB, then verify the insertion, 
unfortunately, when I run the client, I get (no EJB module) class not found in lookup function, SEVERE: EJB6005:No EJB modules found
javax.naming.NamingException: Lookup failed for 'vlibtour.vlibtour_tour_management.api.VlibTourTourManagement' in SerialContext[myEnv={java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialInitContextFactory, java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=com.sun.enterprise.naming, java.naming.factory.state=com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl} [Root exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: vlibtour.vlibtour_tour_management.api.VlibTourTourManagement not found]

noting that it runs well on test junit.
below is some of my code:

interface:

```
@Remote

public interface VlibTourTourManagement {   

String testInsert();

String verifyInsert();

Tour findCustomer(String name);
}
```

bean:

```
public String testInsert() {

Tour tour = new Tour();
tour.setId(1);
tour.setName("first tour");
// Persist the tour
em.persist(tour);

return "ok for tour";
```

}

```
@Override
public String verifyInsert() {
    Tour c = findCustomer("first tour");
    System.out.println(c.getName()+" "+ c.getId());
    return "inserted correctly";
}

@Override
public Tour findCustomer(final String name) {
    Query q = em.createQuery("select c from TOUR c where c.name = :name");
    q.setParameter("name", name);
    return (Tour) q.getSingleResult();
}
```

on client side:

```
@EJB public static VlibTourTourManagement sb;
private static EJBContainer ec;
private static Context ctx;

    Tour c;
    Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    properties.put(EJBContainer.MODULES, new File("target/classes"));
    ec = EJBContainer.createEJBContainer(properties);
    ctx = ec.getContext();
    try {
        sb = (VlibTourTourManagement) ctx.lookup("vlibtour.vlibtour_tour_management.api.VlibTourTourManagement");
        System.out.println("Inserting Tour... " + sb.testInsert());

        System.out.println("Verifying Tour... " + sb.verifyInsert());

    }catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: it seems you created the project in a wrong way as the web app cant see the ejb are you using maven ? if so please make sure you added the ejb dependency

Comment: What server (and version) are you using?